# Checkbox self checking C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my problem and yes I am a newbie

I have a form (dialog) that has two checkboxes (chbxAlpha and chbxBravo), two textboxes (tbxAlpha and tbxBravo) which can only receive 6 char , and two buttons (Submit and Cancel)

The form is loaded by an error event

When the form is loaded if Alpha is the error then I will check Alpha Checkbox and then fill in the error in Alpha Textbox

If chars are < > than 6 a messagebox appears alerting the user that they must submit 6 chars no more and no less

When I press the submit button the form then automatically checks Bravo Checkbox and I have to fill it out even there has been no error

I cannot figure out why

Below is the code

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chbxAlpha.Checked = true && tbxAlpha.Text.Length != 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A valid entry requires 6 digits. Please use forward zeros if data is less than 6 digits eg 1234 = 001234.Thankyou");
            tbxAlpha.Text = "";
            tbxAlpha.Focus();
        }

        else

        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }


        if (chbxBravo.Checked = true && tbxBravo.Text.Length != 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A valid entry requires 6 digits. Please use forward zeros if data is less than 6 digits eg 1234 = 001234.Thankyou");
            tbxBravo.Text = "";
            tbxBravo.Focus();
        }

        else
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }

    private void chbxBravo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chbxBravo.Checked == true)
        {
            tbxBravo.Visible = true;
            tbxBravo.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void chbxAlpha_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chbxAlpha.Checked == true)
        {
            tbxAlpha.Visible = true;
            tbxAlpha.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The other question I have is how can I prevent Null char from being used eg. 123space56

Appreciate any help

JJ

Comment: A typo :  '=' vs '==' operators I guess

Comment: Also rather using == you can simply use Checked property which return a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using an assignment operator rather than an equality operator in both your if statements in btnSubmit_click function.

In answer to your second question, you can use a Regex to check that all 6 characters are digits.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex regexIs6Digits = new Regex(@"^\d{6}$");

    if (chbxAlpha.Checked && !regexIs6Digits.IsMatch(tbxAlpha.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A valid entry requires 6 digits. Please use forward zeros if data is less than 6 digits eg 1234 = 001234.Thankyou");
        tbxAlpha.Text = "";
        tbxAlpha.Focus();
    }

    else

    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }


    if (chbxBravo.Checked && !regexIs6Digits.IsMatch(tbxBravo.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A valid entry requires 6 digits. Please use forward zeros if data is less than 6 digits eg 1234 = 001234.Thankyou");
        tbxBravo.Text = "";
        tbxBravo.Focus();
    }

    else
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better provide code snippet for error .. And suggest a correction too

Comment: Awesome Guys. Its always the little things. Thank you and thanks for the Regex Ant. I actually forgot about that. Again still new. Much to learn. Thanks again Jay Jnr

Comment: Oops. New problem. using the above code "Ant32bit" the dialog from the message box. Thanks in advance JJ

Comment: Its ok. Go it thanks, On my way to work when I realised. Need to add return;